# Black box on right top left corner while switching between workspaces with touchpad

Tags: screen

Black box appears on right top left corner while switching between workspaces with touchpad. And while using chrome, the area that box appears is unclickable. but some other apps arent effected by this.

Comment: Could you share some screenshots please ?